# select text between self closed elements

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to select text between self closed `pet` elements.

Input:

```
<root>
    <pet/>pet1<pet/><pet>cor1</pet><pet>vsr</pet><pet/>mnt<pet/>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<output>
    <ou>pet1</ou>
    <ou>mnt</ou>
</output>
```

Logic:

Here `pet1` and `mnt` is between self closed `<pet/>`. SO i want to select such texts

Tried xpath:

```
text()[preceding-sibling::pet][following-sibling::pet]
```

Above xpath is not working. How can I fix this problem? I am using XSLT 2.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::pet[not(node())]][following-sibling::node()[1][self::pet[not(node())]]` to find text nodes between empty `pet` elements; you can't distinguish between `<pet/>` and `<pet></pet>` in XSLT/XPath, these are lexical differences not reflected in the tree model of XSLT/XPath.